# Powershell MSI installer script

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

Please could somebody help me with the powershell script that I have written below? I just can not seem to get the installer to start:-

```
$msiName = "D:\Folder\Build 1.9.0.39621 Setup.msi”
Write-Host "Installing msi"

$argumentlist = "/i [application] /qn /l*v log.txt LOGDIR=`"D:\Log`" SQLSERVER=`"xxx-xxx-xxxx-2`" DBAUTOBACKUP=`"0`" APPPOOLDOMAIN=`"Test-as`" APPPOOLUSER=`"Testservice`" APPPOOLPASSWD=`"xxxxxxx`" ADQUERY=`"Test-as.net`" ADNAME=`"ultra`""

$application = $msiName
$argumentlist = $argumentlist.Replace("[application]",$application)

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $argumentlist -Wait
```

I have tried to simply it, but it still will not work. Below is a number of different ways I have tried:-

(1st Attempt)

```
$argumentList = "/i `"xxxxxx 1.9.0.39641 Setup.msi`""

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $argumentList
```

(2nd attempt)

```
$argumentList = "/i {0}" -f "xxxxxx 1.9.0.39641 Setup.msi"

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $argumentList
```

(3rd attempt)

```
$argumentList = ("/i {0}" -f "xxxxxx 1.9.0.39641 Setup.msi")

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList $argumentList
```

(4th attempt)

```
$argumentList = ("/i {0}" -f "xxxxxx 1.9.0.39641 Setup.msi")

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "$argumentList"
```

Comment: Can you please post the error log. I guess you've a problem building the `argumentlist`, there is a lot of escaping. I would recommend to build this string via the format operator (http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html , e.g. `$argumentlist=("/i {0}" -f $msiName) ).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried simplifying it, and doing what you suggested (see my edited orignal message), but it still wont working. It wont even start the installer. I just get a dialogue box popup saying what the format of the command line should be for starting the msi i.e. "msiexec /Option <required Parameter> [Optional parameter] ........etc etc

Comment: You'd make your life a lot simpler if you stop putting spaces in your filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used in the past , should work for you.

```
    $argumentList = @(
        "-o",
        "$sourcefile",
        "-d",
        "$targetFolder"
    )
start-process -filepath $file -argumentlist $argumentList -wait -nonewwindow -passthru
```

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the old answer.

**New possible solution**

`ArgumenList` is a string array, therefore it can take multiple arguments.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i", "`"xxx yyyyy.msi`""
```

I tried it with an installer including blanks in the name, worked on my machine.

Hope that helps

Comment: I agree with you: seems there is some escaping problem here. Escaping with backslashes seems ok though. Perhaps try `"$argumentlist"`? I'm not too sure.

Comment: Hi thanks for you responses, but I still can not get it working. I have even tried simplifying it. I have tried the following:-

Comment: Hi Andreas. Thank you for helping. The problem is that I want to use the powershell command 'Start-Process' because I want to add a '-wait' in my powershell script, so that the script does not carry onto the next line of code until the msi installation has completed.

Comment: @ED209, please check the answer update, if it is ok for you or not. thx